# Encrypting a nested map of small strings with the same symmetric key

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cryptography, mongoid, cryptojs

Let's say I have am creating a webapp, where users can create a nested tree of strings (with sensitive information). These strings are presumably quite short. I want to encrypt both keys and values in this tree before saving it. All values in the tree will be encrypted client-side using a symmetric key supplied by the user. Likewise they will be decrypted client-side, when reading.

The tree is persisted in a Mongo database.

I can't decide whether I should serialize the tree and encrypt it has a whole string or whether to encrypt values individually, considering that all data in the tree will be encrypted using the same key.

What are the pros and cons of either?

From what I can tell, AES uses a block size of 128 bits, meaning that any string can grow up to 15 characters in length when encoded, which speaks in favor of encoding a serialized string (if you want to avoid overhead)

Note: Although the webapp will use both HTTPS, IP whitelisting and multifactor authentication, I want to make an effort to prevent data breach in the event the Mongo database is stolen. That's what I'm going for here. Advice or thoughts on how to accomplish this is appreciated.

#### Update

**Furthermore, I also want my service to inspire trust. Sending data in the clear (although over HTTPS) means the user must trust me to encrypt it before persisting it. Encrypting client-side allows me to emphasize that I don't know (or need to know) what I'm saving.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a reason why these approaches would be different in terms of security of the actual strings (assuming they are both implemented correctly). Encrypting the strings individually obviously means that the structure of the tree will not be secret, but I'm not sure if you are concerned with that or not. For example, if you encrypt each string individually, someone seeing the ciphertexts could find out how many keys there are in the tree, and he could also learn something about the length of each key and value. If you encrypt the tree as a whole serialized blob, then someone seeing the ciphertext can tell roughly how much data is in the tree but nothing about the lengths or number of individual keys/values.

In terms of overhead, the padding would be a consideration, as you mentioned. A bigger source of storage overhead is IVs: if you are using a block cipher mode such as CTR, you need to use a distinct IV for each ciphertext. This means if you are encrypting each string individually, you need to store an IV for each string. If you encrypt the whole serialized tree, then you just need to store the one IV for that one ciphertext.

Before you implement this in Javascript, though, you should make sure that you're actually getting a real improvement in security from doing client-side encryption. This article is a classic: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/ One important point is to remember that the server is providing the Javascript encryption code, so encrypting data on the client doesn't protect it from the server. If your main concern is a stolen database, you could achieve the same security by just encrypting the data on the server before inserting it in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I read the article and that's an interesting perspective. Unless the user brings their own crypto library, this won't guard against MITM attacks.

However, if no encryption is done client-side, it would be easy for any reviewer of my service to claim that users are showing me unpredecented trust, by submitting data in the clear (although over HTTPS) and entrusting me to encrypt it before persisting it.

I think I will have an easier time winning hearts and minds if wireshark indicates that I don't know what I am storing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am not a security *expert* ;-)

> I can't decide whether I should serialize the tree and encrypt it has a whole string or whether to encrypt values individually, considering that all data in the tree will be encrypted using the same key.

I would say serializing the tree first and encrypting the result of that has the biggest **con**.

What plays a huge role in successfully cracking encryption is often the knowledge about certain characters that appear quite often in the original text – for example the letters e and n in English language – and doing statistical analysis based on that on the encrypted text.

Now lets say you use for example JSON to serialize your tree client-side before encrypting it. As the attacker, I would easily know that, since I can analyze your client-side script at my leisure. So I also know already that the “letters” {, }, [, ], : and " will have a high percentage of occurrence in every “text” that you encrypt … and that the first letter of every text will have been either a { or a [ (based upon whether your tree is an object or an array) – that’s already quite a bit of potentially very useful knowledge about the texts that get encrypted by your app.

Comment: Frequency analysis isn't a concern for modern cryptosystems. If it were, we'd be in a whole lot of trouble. :) For example, an attacker watching HTTPS traffic knows that almost all requests start with "GET" or "POST", but that doesn't help him decrypt the rest of the request. Of course there are insecure ways to encrypt data such that frequency analysis would be helpful to the attacker (e.g. AES in ECB mode), but if the OP is using a decent high-level cryptography library, then it's easy to use a secure cipher mode where these attacks don't apply.